# Migrating Data Between Dynamics CRM 2011 Instances?

Tags: database, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a Dynamics CRM 2011 instance where the database has become corrupted. The corrupted data appears to be isolated to a few tables (e.g. PrincipalObjectAccess) and the instance still functions normally to all appearances. The data is irretrievable (all forms of DBCC CHECKDB, etc. have been run) and a backup is not available (preaching on backups will not help resolve the issue).

I've tried using schema and data synchronization tools like those offered by dbForge and Red-Gate, the schema sync works but the data sync always seems to come up inconsistent.

At this juncture I think my best route is probably to export all data from Dynamics CRM 2011 and then import it into a new instance of Dynamics CRM 2011. Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this? Or alternative methods of rectifying the situation?

Answer (score 4):

Exporting all data and importing it into new organization will likely create more errors and I wouldn't really go with that option unless everything else fails.

You said data synchronization failed: have you tried deleting all data from new instance first and then running data synchronization. It should be simpler than synchronization when data already exists there.

Have you tried synchronizing data using [ApexSQL Data Diff](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_datadiff.aspx) ?

Another option you can try that doesn't require you to create new organization is reading your SQL Server transaction logs and checking if corrupted data can be found there. If you can retrieve the data then you can just re-create tables with valid data and you'll be all good. Unfortunately this is only possible using 3rd pary tools such as [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend looking into the CRM 2011 Instance Adapter

Unlike Scribe, it's free.

Microsoft blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2012/10/24/the-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-instance-adapter-has-released.aspx

PowerObjects wrote an article about it as well: 
http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/10/26/introduction-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-instance-adapter/

Peter

Answer (score 2):

If you can, export to Excel and import from there.
*Advantage: easy, fast, graspable*

If you can't, design a console application that connects to the server, queries it, fetches data and shoves it into the other instance.
*Advantage: full control, repeatibility, configurability, coolness factor and you get to type some code*

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the scope of your data.  Are you talking about millions of records with a huge list of entities or are you talking a couple entities with a thousand or so records?

If it's something small, you could always try exporting via excel and then importing into the new org.

SSIS, CozyRoc or Scribe will do the trick.  I'd opt for Scribe and go entity by entity if it is a mission critical situation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is a few entities, some with 100k-500k records.